# Cannot Close Rotation Tool

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I cannot find the answer to my issue so sorry if the question is a duplicate. I cannot close my rotation tool and am not sure what I hit.

See pic please and thank you!

M

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you may have the Rotate option checked in the Show Gizmo dropdown as shown below. Normally all the Object gizmos are unchecked on that menu by default.

[image]

This applies to both Edit and Object mode.

Comment: That was it, not sure how it got checked. Thank you!

Comment: Good! I've never used it here, but did know that the setting existed! :^)